# how to find all the text in a column where text without white space

Tags: python, pandas

I have data frame which has a column `text` it contain many text.I want to display only the text without white space.
eg.,

'hi how are you'  - I dont want this

'good'     - want this.

final column look like

`hi`

`good`

Comment: Could you be more explicit- what's your input exactly (3-4 lines of your data frame) and the desired output (i.e. how this dataframe should look like after the operation you are asking for).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
In [512]: df  
Out[512]: 
             text
0  hi how are you
1            good
2   hello friends

## check for whitespaces and take a `not` of it    
In [516]: df = df[~df.text.str.contains(' ')] 

In [516]: df 
Out[516]: 
   text
1  good
```